# How to get first object that satisfies a given condition

Tags: javascript

I have a sample script

```
const building_arr = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Test 1', city_id: 5 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Test 2', city_id: 1 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Test 3', city_id: 1 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Test 4', city_id: 3 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Test 5', city_id: 5 },
];
let building_object = {};
building_object = building_arr.filter(function (building) {
    if (building.id == 1) return building;
});
```

I want get first object `{id:1,name:"Test 2",city_id:1}`, but result not work

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `find` rather than `filter`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find